# VSTO add-in opens the default workbook every time Excel is opened

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have developed an Excel add-in and installed it on my machine.  When I open Excel on my desktop (`sample.xlsx`), it always opens it along with the default workbook `Book1.xlsx`.  When I verfied the Addins menu I see the addin appear twice in `Excel -> Addins` menu.

Can we set a condition where if an addin with a similar name is already loaded then it will not be loaded again?

Comment: Are you saying that you have an addin named "sample.xlsx"?

Answer (score 0):

Check the registry entries under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Excel\Addins  if you more than one entries delete the one which you dont require.

Also check the same under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE